# Flutter: Open Auth with url launcher

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth, url-launcher

I'm trying to make a system that makes an open auth operation using the url launcher in Flutter, then redirects it when the process is complete, and returns the application and captures the authorization_code.

In step one, I redirect to the url I want and provide login, but it doesn't return to the application and I'm not sure how to capture the authorization_code.

here is sample code:

```
 final url = Uri.https('auth_link', '/login', {
      'client_id': "clientid",
      'redirect_uri': 'myappurlschemes',
      'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
      'response_type': 'code',
      'code_challenge': codeChallenge,
      'code_challenge_method': 'S256',
      'scope': 'openid+profile+offline_access+email',
    });
```

Actually, I can do this with webview, but I want to use the default browser of the device. And I don't need to use any oauth packages.